# How to Install Xamarian on My Android Glad X10.1

Tags: c#, android, installation, apk, dmg

I am a newbee to c#.  Please treat me as a beginner.  I downloaded and installed Ximarian C# and the IDEA on my Windows 10 computer.  Now, I want to install it onto my LGA ANDROID Gpad X10.1 so I can study and learn C# when I am not at home; I want to write programs for Android using my Android Tablet.  I did some homework and found out I had to go to Security and check unknown devices which I did.  I downloaded the Xararianinstaller.dmg file (I can't) figure out where Xamarian keeps the APK file).So the XamarianInstaller.dmg file is sitting in my download folder but it will not execute. Android does not recognize the. Dmg file or know which program to run the installer with.

1. How do I get the .dmg file to execute?  What do I need to do?
2. Where are the latest APK files kept,how can I download and install them?

I have an LG GLAD X10.1
Android Version 6.0
Kernel 3.4.0
Build MRA5BK
Version: V93020f

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to inform you this, but you will not be able to use your Android device to extract and execute the `.dmg` file.

Xamarian is a compiler/API that installs onto a Windows/iOS device (which you have done) but it is used to plan, develop and build your projects.

Android does use APK (Android Application Package) file formats to install and run their applications. The confusion you have is that there is some sort of APK for Xamarian to install it native on your tablet. This will not work ***but what you can do is test your build applications on the go with your tablet with a compiled APK file from Xamaarian from your computer***.

Android can not run `.dmg` file extensions and can run very few renditions of .exe files native but your best bet is to simply build and test/debug on your device. Use the device as an extension to your Computer not a stand alone solution.

Happy Coding.